# Use Async Modifire for an abstract methode

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.android

I want to use a async work but my method is override from an abstract and i can't add "Async Task" to that method...

This is the method:

```cs
public  override View  OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var _view=something;
    await dosomthing();
    return _view;
}
```

//----------------------------
as you can see i want to do something like that...
and the only way that i could find so far is this(look at the below code)

```cs
public  override View  OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var _view=null;
    var mytsk = Task<View>.Run(async () =>
    {
        var _view=something;
        await dosomthing();`
    });

    //I dont know where should i return my "_view" that my Ui thread dosent gets locked
}
```

if when the task finished i write "mytsk.result" then my Ui Get Locked!!!!
if i use (below code)

```cs
var _view=null;

var mytsk = Task<View>.Run(async () =>
{
    var _view=something;
    await dosomthing();`
}).wait();

return _view;
```

then my UI Get Locked...
please for the love of god Help me :(

Answer (score 1):

All UI updates must be synchronous. When the platform asks your app for a view, it ***must*** return a view immediately. Your app is trying to say "hold on for some time while I do something, and then I'll let you know what to display", which is not allowed.

To fix this, you'll need to introduce some kind of a "loading" view - e.g., with just a placeholder or spinner or something. When your app is asked for the view, you can *start* an asynchronous operation and then return the "loading" view. Later, when that operation completes, your app can *update* the view to the "real" view.

Answer (score -1):

You can only use the `async` keyword with methods returning `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`and since your overriding method returns `View` you can't use `async` with it.

If when you say

> Ui Get Locked!!!!

You mean the UI becomes unresponsive, then you'd need to make the asynchronous call from a place that does support asynchronous calls (e.g. `OnResume`) or subscribe to an event and do it there. 
For example:

```
button.Click += async (sender, e) => 
    {
        var _view = something;
        await doSomethingAsync();
    };
```

Another option would be to simply not wait for the asynchronous process to finish, but this depends on your requirements.

Comment: thanks for your answer....but your answer doesnt helped me...
as i  said "I dont know how to return my view without any UI thread Locking...!!!"

imaging you have my problom how you fix it???
{
}

Comment: I gave you multiple possibilities to fix your problem (e.g. `button.Click +=...`). Just pick the one that best suits your needs...